# Cannot run Grails Spec using JUnit on IntelliJ IDEA since version 2.3.2

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, intellij-idea, spock

I'm in the process of upgrading our application from Grails 2.2.4 to 2.3.4 and everything seems to go quite easy. The only thing that is driving me nuts is that I can't run a Tests or a Spec class (or a collection of them) using the JUnit runner within IDEA (both version 12 and 13).

I get this exception:
Class not found: "test.PersonControllerSpec"
Process finished with exit code 1

I can "make" the project successfully and I can run the tests using the Grails runner too.
Seems like IDEA doesn't compile the test code or something like that.

Funnily it works like a charm in STS so it can't come from Grails.

Here is the full target ... might help:

Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=Z:\dev\tools\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "Z:\dev\tools\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\lib\idea_rt.jar;Z:\dev\tools\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\javaws.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\plugin.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;Z:\dev\code\Test\out\test\Test;Z:\dev\code\Test\out\production\Test;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\2.0.5\liquibase-core-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\core\compiler\ecj\3.7.2\ecj-3.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk14\138\bcprov-jdk14-138.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.16.1-GA\javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\grails\grails-datastore-web\1.1.9.RELEASE\grails-datastore-web-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-mongodb\1.2.1.RELEASE\spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongo-java-driver\2.11.1\mongo-java-driver-2.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4.3\mail-1.4.3.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\mozilla\rhino\1.7R4\rhino-1.7R4.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\grails\grails-datastore-mongo\1.3.0.RELEASE\grails-datastore-mongo-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\grails\grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support\1.1.9.RELEASE\grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons-core\1.4.1.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\grails\grails-datastore-gorm-mongo\1.3.0.RELEASE\grails-datastore-gorm-mongo-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\com\gmongo\gmongo\1.2\gmongo-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.2.1\httpcore-4.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.2.1\httpclient-4.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.35.0\selenium-api-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.35.0\selenium-remote-driver-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\asm\asm-tree\3.0\asm-tree-3.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cobertura\cobertura\1.9.4.1\cobertura-1.9.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\gmetrics\GMetrics\0.5\GMetrics-0.5.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\codenarc\CodeNarc\0.19\CodeNarc-0.19.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\2.35.0\selenium-support-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.5.2.Final\netty-3.5.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\webbitserver\webbit\0.4.14\webbit-0.4.14.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\2.35.0\selenium-safari-driver-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-android-driver\2.35.0\selenium-android-driver-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-iphone-driver\2.35.0\selenium-iphone-driver-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\2.35.0\selenium-ie-driver-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\2.35.0\selenium-chrome-driver-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.35.0\selenium-firefox-driver-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\8.1.9.v20130131\jetty-http-8.1.9.v20130131.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\8.1.9.v20130131\jetty-io-8.1.9.v20130131.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\8.1.9.v20130131\jetty-util-8.1.9.v20130131.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-websocket\8.1.9.v20130131\jetty-websocket-8.1.9.v20130131.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.9\cssparser-0.9.9.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.18\nekohtml-1.9.18.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.10.0\xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.12\htmlunit-core-js-2.12.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.2.3\httpmime-4.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.12\htmlunit-2.12.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-htmlunit-driver\2.35.0\selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.35.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.1\commons-exec-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-core\2.4.6\ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\7.0.42\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-jasper\7.0.42\tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.42.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-catalina-ant\7.0.42\tomcat-catalina-ant-7.0.42.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.3\joda-time-2.3.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-logging-log4j\7.0.42\tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.42.jar;C:\Users\Nico.m2\repository\org\spockframework\spock-grails-support\0.7-groovy-2.0\spock-grails-support-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-aether-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-async-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-core-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-databinding-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-docs-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-logging-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-async-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-codecs-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-controllers-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-converters-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-databinding-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-datasource-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-domain-class-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-filters-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-gsp-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-i18n-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-log4j-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-mimetypes-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-rest-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-services-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-servlets-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-testing-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-url-mappings-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-plugin-validation-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-resources-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-scripts-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-spring-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-test-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-web-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-wrapper-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\dist\grails-wrapper-support-2.3.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\aopalliance\aopalliance\jars\aopalliance-1.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\asm\asm\jars\asm-3.3.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\bouncycastle\bcmail-jdk14\jars\bcmail-jdk14-138.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk14\jars\bcprov-jdk14-138.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\cglib\cglib\jars\cglib-2.2.2.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\jars\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\com.google.code.gson\gson\jars\gson-2.2.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\com.google.guava\guava\jars\guava-10.0.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\com.google.protobuf\protobuf-java\jars\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru\jars\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\com.googlecode.json-simple\json-simple\jars\json-simple-1.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\com.h2database\h2\jars\h2-1.3.173.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\com.lowagie\itext\jars\itext-2.0.8.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\jars\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-cli\commons-cli\jars\commons-cli-1.2.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-codec\commons-codec\jars\commons-codec-1.6.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-collections\commons-collections\jars\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-el\commons-el\jars\commons-el-1.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\jars\commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-io\commons-io\jars\commons-io-2.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-lang\commons-lang\jars\commons-lang-2.6.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\commons-validator\commons-validator\jars\commons-validator-1.3.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\hsqldb\hsqldb\jars\hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\javax.annotation\jsr250-api\jars\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\javax.enterprise\cdi-api\jars\cdi-api-1.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\javax.inject\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\javax.servlet\javax.servlet-api\jars\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\javax.servlet\jsp-api\jars\jsp-api-2.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\javax.servlet\jstl\jars\jstl-1.1.2.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\javax.servlet.jsp\jsp-api\jars\jsp-api-2.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\javax.transaction\jta\jars\jta-1.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\jline\jline\jars\jline-2.11.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\junit\junit\jars\junit-4.11.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\log4j\log4j\jars\log4j-1.2.17.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\net.java.dev.jna\jna\jars\jna-4.0.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\opensymphony\sitemesh\jars\sitemesh-2.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.ant\ant\jars\ant-1.8.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.ant\ant-junit\jars\ant-junit-1.8.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.ant\ant-launcher\jars\ant-launcher-1.8.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.ant\ant-trax\jars\ant-trax-1.7.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\jars\httpclient-4.2.5.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\jars\httpcore-4.2.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.ivy\ivy\jars\ivy-2.3.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.maven\maven-aether-provider\jars\maven-aether-provider-3.1.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.maven\maven-model\jars\maven-model-3.1.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.maven\maven-model-builder\jars\maven-model-builder-3.1.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.maven\maven-repository-metadata\jars\maven-repository-metadata-3.1.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.maven\maven-settings\jars\maven-settings-3.1.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.maven\maven-settings-builder\jars\maven-settings-builder-3.1.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.tomcat\tomcat-jdbc\jars\tomcat-jdbc-7.0.47.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-logging-log4j\jars\tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.47.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjrt\jars\aspectjrt-1.7.2.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\jars\aspectjweaver-1.7.2.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.bouncycastle\bcpg-jdk15\jars\bcpg-jdk15-1.45.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15\jars\bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.codehaus.gant\gant_groovy1.8\jars\gant_groovy1.8-1.9.6.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.codehaus.gpars\gpars\jars\gpars-1.1.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.1.9.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror\jsr166y\jars\jsr166y-1.7.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.codehaus.plexus\plexus-classworlds\jars\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.codehaus.plexus\plexus-component-annotations\jars\plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.codehaus.plexus\plexus-interpolation\jars\plexus-interpolation-1.19.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.codehaus.plexus\plexus-utils\jars\plexus-utils-3.0.15.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.aether\aether-api\jars\aether-api-0.9.0.M3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.aether\aether-connector-basic\jars\aether-connector-basic-0.9.0.M3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.aether\aether-connector-file\jars\aether-connector-file-0.9.0.M2.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.aether\aether-impl\jars\aether-impl-0.9.0.M3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.aether\aether-spi\jars\aether-spi-0.9.0.M3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.aether\aether-transport-file\jars\aether-transport-file-0.9.0.M3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.aether\aether-transport-http\jars\aether-transport-http-0.9.0.M3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.aether\aether-util\jars\aether-util-0.9.0.M3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.sisu\org.eclipse.sisu.inject\jars\org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M5.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.eclipse.sisu\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus\jars\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.0.0.M5.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\jars\jansi-1.11.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.grails\grails-datastore-core\jars\grails-datastore-core-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.grails\grails-datastore-gorm\jars\grails-datastore-gorm-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.grails\grails-datastore-simple\jars\grails-datastore-simple-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.grails\grails-gdoc-engine\jars\grails-gdoc-engine-1.0.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\jars\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.hibernate.javax.persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\jars\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.javassist\javassist\jars\javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.multiverse\multiverse-core\jars\multiverse-core-0.7.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.objenesis\objenesis\jars\objenesis-1.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\jars\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\jars\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.slf4j\slf4j-simple\jars\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.sonatype.plexus\plexus-cipher\jars\plexus-cipher-1.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.sonatype.plexus\plexus-sec-dispatcher\jars\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.sonatype.sisu\sisu-guice\jars\sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.spockframework\spock-core\jars\spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-aop\jars\spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-aspects\jars\spring-aspects-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-beans\jars\spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-context\jars\spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-context-support\jars\spring-context-support-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-core\jars\spring-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-expression\jars\spring-expression-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\jars\spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-jms\jars\spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-test\jars\spring-test-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-tx\jars\spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-web\jars\spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\jars\spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springframework.uaa\org.springframework.uaa.client\jars\org.springframework.uaa.client-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.springsource.springloaded\springloaded-core\jars\springloaded-core-1.1.4.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.xhtmlrenderer\core-renderer\jars\core-renderer-R8.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\org.yaml\snakeyaml\jars\snakeyaml-1.8.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\oro\oro\jars\oro-2.0.8.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\taglibs\standard\jars\standard-1.1.2.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\xalan\serializer\jars\serializer-2.7.1.jar;Z:\dev\frameworks\grails-2.3.4\lib\xpp3\xpp3_min\jars\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 test.PersonControllerSpec

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have discovered the problem.  Look at the folder designation type.  My IntelliJ12 project file marked the "test root" as "test resources root" and I was not paying close enough attention.  Remove the "Mark Directory As" and set as "Test Root".  I am now able to run Groovy test cases